# ClassFormatError : Unknown constant tag

Tags: java, windows, alfresco

I do face a problem with Java when sending an URL to Alfresco.

When a user logs into the my website, through Joomla, the server calls for the CRM, then passes the credentials to Alfresco

[image: constant tag unknown]

The URL is designed as follows : 
https://example.com:8553/alfresco/testlogin.jsp?Itemid=1&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWD

A little background of the project :

This occurs on a replicate of an existing (and functional) webserver. The error appears when logging into the new webserver, which is an exact replication of the previously used server.

Browsing the web I've found several answers suggering to either copy and paste the Java folder, or to re-install it directly. I did both of those and none of them worked so far.

Moreover, this is the alfrescoTomcat log, which is the same as shown on the screenshot :

```
Jul 31, 2017 3:01:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 61 in class file org/apache/jsp/testlogin_jsp
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:621)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

This is the only difference with the old server logs.

I am kinda new to such problems and would require your help to get this through. Either by redirecting me to a correct solution I may have missed or by clearing it up for me.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am gonna give this tip if anyone encounters the same problem :

What I did to fix this error was simply to rename my script (the one who triggered the error) to old.script.jsp. Then using notepad++ I copied/pasted the code and saved it under the old name script.jsp.

Everything works fine by now.